# Hide/Remove unused State Category in Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I accidentally activated the state category for "Resolved" under Task-states when making a new state. I removed the new state, but the column for the state category is still listed under my sprint and takes up unnecessary space.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM1ud.png)

Been looking through all settings but the "State category" doesnt seem to be listed anywhere?
How do I remove/hide it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eURVw.png)